# JavaScript: Function.prototype

Tags: javascript

Below is some code copied from "good parts", with some modification.

program.html

```
<html><body><pre><script src="program.js">
</script></pre></body></html>
```

program.js

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

var Quo_2 = function (string) {
    this.status = string;
};

Quo_2.method(get_status, function () { return this.status; });

var myQuo_2 = new Quo_2("confused 2");

document.writeln(myQuo_2.get_status());
```

Error

```
ReferenceError: get_status is not defined
```

Comment: maybe if you explained what you're trying to accomplish, or posed a question, you wouldn't get the down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_status` should be a string. You're trying to pass a variable, but the function accepts a string as the function name.

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
    this.prototype[name] = func;
    return this;
};

var Quo_2 = function (string) {
    this.status = string;
};
// added quotes around get_status
Quo_2.method('get_status', function () { return this.status; });

var myQuo_2 = new Quo_2("confused 2");

document.writeln(myQuo_2.get_status());
```